# How to control the length of a text box

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to control the length of the text box. The property of the textbox only has maxlength tool. If I want to set minimum length for textbox to be 3, how can I proceed this?

I want an error to pop up when someone types 10 instead of 100. User can only put a combination of 1 and 0 like 100,000,010,001, etc. Type of these are double.(not string)

Comment: is this a vb.net windows Application or Web Application?

Comment: So setting the `Maxlength` to 3 does not work for you? I don't understand what your asking for. Your second part does not make sense either, please elaborate

Comment: It is windows application. Maxlength works but I want an error to pop up if people only type 2 numbers or 1 number in the texbox.

Comment: For example, numbers 1, 11 should make an error when I run the codes because I want to say minimum length is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handle the Textbox control validating event. [**See this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)